# Access external css file in Tomcat error pages

Tags: css, tomcat

I have a Tomcat 10 setup in a development environment with a custom 403 error page. My 403 error page look something like this.

```
<html>

<head>

   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"
      title="Default" href="default/style-1.0.2.css" />
   <link rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" title="Paper White" 
      href="default/print-1.0.1.min.css" />
   
   <title>403 Forbidden</title>

</head>
<body>

   <h3>You do not have required permissions to view this page.</h3>

</body>

</html>
```

When I reproduce this, I am getting a 403 error while accessing external CSS files.

[403 error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BY0I7.png)

My theory is that as the tomcat recognizes this request as 403, it is not allowing the request to access the underlying CSS resources as well.

Is there a way to bypass this?

Comment: For each resource your browser issues a separate request. You are probably denying to some client access to all resources: can you add your security restrictions to your question?

Comment: Yes, I am denying the client access to all resources based on the LDAP group. If the user is a member of a particular group, the user can view the webpage.

Comment: My point is: you deny access also to the CSS resources. Hence you need to exclude your CSS resources from your security constraints.